# How Set Child Category under Parent Category in Joomla Virtuemart

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

Here I have a problem, when I create a subcategory it goes to main menu and I need to show it in body where main category shows .. Simply I need my category setting like this, so how I can do this please.

Both sites use "Virtuemart".  What do I need to do for this kind of result?

I need this http://www.empiremedia.biz/ Like this  http://www.unitedbroadcast.com/

Anyone who well experienced in Virtuemart. or how i can solve my issue ,please guide or suggest me what need to do?  Or where do I need to change core files?

Comment: Which version of: VM and J!?

Comment: i have joomlia 1.6 and Virtuemart 2.0.14

Comment: try the checking the "Show Children Category" one... it is available in the 2.0.10 that I'm running ;)

Comment: yes i see children category is on in shopfront setting. so how i can use links to his subcategories in parent directories. or any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking "Show Children Category" in the Templates tab of the Config menu.  (VM 2.0.10)

To do this:

1. Go to Virtuemart > Configuration
2. Click the Templates tabs
3. Select the "Show Children Category" check box
4. Save

Option 2:

1. Go to Virtuemart > Products > Product Categories
2. Click the product category you want to edit.
3. In the description box type in the name of your sub category then make it a link to that sub category... if you need the link navigate to it in your browser.

Again I can't stress this enough if you have having THIS MUCH trouble with VM I strongly suggest getting a book or hiring a developer.  Please consider [buying a VM book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1475144636).

Comment: thanks but can you tell me how i can links to subcategories in parent categories . and i didn't find your 2nd option. please can you guide me step by step?

Comment: yes i already check that. it's on check. so what's next about your first method? or anything else

Comment: So how i can do it please? i thing they use your 1st option. how i can do this simply suggest me please.

Answer (score 0):

set your homepage or any of your pages 'menu item type' to virtue mart category layout.

on your admin page go to

menu > main menu 
click 'home' or any other page
select virtuemart category layout on the menu item type*

Comment: thanks for reply. i have set that in your way but still same problem.. now i restore it back to frong page type in menu viturmart.. so what i need to do next?